# Xamarin.Forms Android Emulator no Connection

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, emulation

I have a little problem with the VS (Visual Studio) Android Emulator.
The Emulator it self has internet connection. I can Brows and everything.

The Problem is the emulator and the Xamarin.Forms app.

i testet this on the Emulator:

```
var current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;

        if (current != NetworkAccess.Internet)
        {
            //TODO: Fehlermeldung wegen keinem Internet
            return;
        }

        var isReachable = await CrossConnectivity.Current.IsReachable("google.com", 5000);
```

**isReachable**  is **false** on the emulator but **true** when i test it with a *real device*.
what could the problem be?

Answer (score 1):

Android Emulator shares the same network in local computer.

So first make sure that `Google` is accessible from local broswer .

Then try `IsRemoteReachable` instead of `IsReachable` .

Check https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/ConnectivityPlugin/PingaHost.html.